# Make straight line between two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I make straight line between two nodes when one node, for example, above another one and shorter.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

% We need layers to draw the block diagram
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{ann} = [above, text width=5em]
\tikzstyle{naveqs} = [sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners]
\tikzstyle{mainblock} = [above,sensor, text width=6em, fill=yellow!20,
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners, dashed]

\tikzstyle{main} = [rounded corners, fill=yellow!20,
    minimum width=7cm,minimum height=5cm, text centered]

\tikzstyle{submain} = [node distance=0.4cm, rounded corners, fill=red!20,
    minimum width=6.5cm,minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw, rectangle]

\tikzstyle{subsubmain} = [node distance=0.2cm, rounded corners,   fill=green!20,
    minimum width=6cm,minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{header} = [submain, fill=blue!10]
\def\blockdist{2.3}
\def\edgedist{2.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.0]
\node (mobprint)[main,draw,rectangle] {};
\path (mobprint.north) node (exper) [header] {MobilePrint Application};
\node (gui) [submain,below=of exper] {GUI Interface};
\node (pssub) [submain, below=of gui, minimum height=3cm] {Subsystem};
\node (opmap) [subsubmain, above=0.1cm of pssub.south,
minimum width] {Option Mapping};
\node (storage) [subsubmain, above left=0.4cm and 0cm of opmap.north east, minimum width=3cm] {Compressed Storage};
\path [draw, ->] (storage) -- (opmap);
\draw (storage) edge (opmap);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**P.S.:** I wish to connect **(storage)** "Compressed Storage" **to (opmap)** "Option Mapping"

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you intend to put `storage` to the upper right part of `mapping` and `pssub` to the upper left part of `mapping`?

Comment: Could you please clarify which nodes you wish to connect.

Comment: Sorry, updated original question.

Comment: Try `\draw [->] (storage) -- (storage |- opmap.north);`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an attempt, although I have to admit I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve here. Do you want to draw a *vertical* line from `storage` node to `opmap`? Then the `coordinate system perpendicular` is your friend. See page 130 of the [`pgfmanual`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf). Here, we used the implicit syntax `(<p>|- <q>)`. I also repositioned the `Subsystem` label as it is being covered by the `storage` node.

Finally, the code.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5,convert]{standalone}

%\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,times}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{empty}

% We need layers to draw the block diagram
%\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
%\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
%\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

% Define a few styles and constants
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{sensor}=[draw, fill=blue!20, text width=5em, 
    text centered, minimum height=2.5em]
\tikzstyle{ann} = [above, text width=5em]
\tikzstyle{naveqs} = [sensor, text width=6em, fill=red!20, 
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners]
\tikzstyle{mainblock} = [above,sensor, text width=6em, fill=yellow!20,
    minimum height=12em, rounded corners, dashed]

\tikzstyle{main} = [rounded corners, fill=yellow!20,
    minimum width=7cm,minimum height=5cm, text centered]

\tikzstyle{submain} = [node distance=0.4cm, rounded corners, fill=red!20,
    minimum width=6.5cm,minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw, rectangle]

\tikzstyle{subsubmain} = [node distance=0.2cm, rounded corners,   fill=green!20,
    minimum width=6cm,minimum height=0.7cm, text centered, draw, rectangle]
\tikzstyle{header} = [submain, fill=blue!10]
%\def\blockdist{2.3}
%\def\edgedist{2.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3.0]
\node (mobprint)[main,draw,rectangle] {};
\path (mobprint.north) node (exper) [header] {MobilePrint Application};
\node (gui) [submain,below=of exper] {GUI Interface};
\node (pssub) [submain, below=of gui, minimum height=3cm] {};
\node (opmap) [subsubmain, above=0.1cm of pssub.south,
minimum width] {Option Mapping};
\node (storage) [subsubmain, above left=0.4cm and 0cm of opmap.north east, minimum width=3cm] {Compressed Storage};

% Draw a line from storage perpendicular to opmap
\draw [->] (storage) -- (storage |- opmap.north); 
% Position the label at the top portion of pssub node
\node at (pssub.north) [anchor=north] {Subsystem};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

By the way, consider replacing your `\tikzstyle`'s with `\tikzset`. I have also commented some lines of code that were not used. You can uncomment them later in your  actual use case. Also, consider using `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` in place of `times` package.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted - draw vertical line from one node to another.